# serial.write() send fails

Tags: python, pyserial

`serial.write()` sends the data;
but the data is generated by the function `create_data`;
send about 10 counts, it will fail.
But if you don't generate by `create_data`,
and use the annotating code string data, it always succeeds.
What's wrong here?

```
def create_data():
    op_list = []
    for i in range(64):
        op3 = random.randint(0, 255)
        op_list.append(hex(op3))
    can_data = " ".join(random.sample(op_list, 8))
    canfd_data = ' '.join(op_list)
    return canfd_data
def master_send():
    com5.write("/app/bin/ip link set can0 down\n".encode())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    com5.write("/app/bin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 100000 dbitrate 1000000 fd on\n".encode())
    time.sleep(0.1)

    for i in range(200):
        # data = "0x3a 0x3a 0xcd 0xef 0x5d 0x59 0x1a 0x4 0x88 0xa8 0x2d 0x2c 0x64 0xf1 0xe4 0xd4 0x37 0xff 0xa3 0xe4 0x2b 0xa9 0xae 0xbf 0x85 0x45 0xbb 0x8c 0x18 0x13 0x76 0x54 0x2 0xf0 0xb4 0x80 0x3 0x87 0xa0 0xa9 0x43 0x67 0x30 0xbf 0x57 0x9f 0x37 0x3d 0x1e 0xf1 0x8d 0x27 0xbe 0x18 0xe5 0x79 0x78 0x71 0x36 0x5b 0x67 0x17 0x73 0x2 0x6d"
        # canfd_cmd = f"/app/bin/cansend can0 -b -i {canfd_id} {canfd_data} \n".encode()
        data = create_data()
        canfd_cmd = f"/app/bin/cansend can0  -b -i 0x100 {data} \n".encode()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        com5.write(canfd_cmd)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will send fail"? Is there an error message?

Comment: by debug , i find serial.read()  nothing, so i guess write fail.```        while time.time() - start < timeout:
            bt = self.com.inWaiting()
            if bt > 0:
                data = self.com.read(bt).decode()```

Comment: IF  i send the data is data = "0x3a 0x3a 0xcd 0xef 0x5d 0x59 0x1a 0x4 0x88 0xa8 0x2d 0x2c 0x64 0xf1 0xe4 0xd4 0x37 0xff 0xa3 0xe4 0x2b 0xa9 0xae 0xbf 0x85 0x45 0xbb 0x8c 0x18 0x13 0x76 0x54 0x2 0xf0 0xb4 0x80 0x3 0x87 0xa0 0xa9 0x43 0x67 0x30 0xbf 0x57 0x9f 0x37 0x3d 0x1e 0xf1 0x8d 0x27 0xbe 0x18 0xe5 0x79 0x78 0x71 0x36 0x5b 0x67 0x17 0x73 0x2 0x6d" it will be received

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what the problem is due to confusing English. Can you try rewriting the question? What is `serial.write()`, it's never refernced in the code. What does 'sending about 10 counts' mean?